# How to create a vertical slide bar in html through transitional effects using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Consider my following code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td onclick="shownav()">Equations of Circle
      <div id="myDownnav" class="sidenav">
        <a>General Info</a>
        <a>In Polar Coordinates</a>
        <a>From two end-points of the diameter</a>
        <a>Passing through three points</a>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want the four links under `div` of id `myDownnav` to be shown upon clicking the `td` element `Equations of Circle`. Here, I have the following CSS-styles:

```
.sidenav{
  height: 0; /*Changes with JavaScript*/
  width: 100%; 
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav down*/
}

/* The navigation menu links */
.sidenav a {
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: inherit;
  color: lightsteelblue;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
.sidenav a:hover {
  color: lightsteelblue;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0);
}
```

Finally, my JavaScript function shownav():

```
function shownav(){
  var z=document.getElementById('myDownnav').style;
    document.getElementById("myDownnav").style.height =z.height==0? '100%': 0;
}
```

What are the things that I need to change? I face the following problems:

1. All the four links are previously shown, even before I click on the `td`
2. After clicking the `td`, only the background changes.
3. I can never make the links to disappear even after a number of clicks though I have made the `div` to be of height 0.
   N.B. I already know that using `onclick` or other inline functions is much discouraged. Any other suggestions would be accepted.

Comment: this is not a task for a table. Tables are only to display tabular data not for styling purposes. Read into Flexbox and CSS-Grid. the transition only works as part of an animation that you have never declared or specified. Note, that you can only transition between 2 states that allow fractions of each other. You can not transition from `display: block` to `display: none` or vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.sidenav{
  max-height: 0; /* Changes with JavaScript */
  width: 100%; 
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav down*/
}

.sidenav.show {
    max-height: 500px;
}
```

```js
function shownav(){
    let nav = document.querySelector('.sidenav');
    nav.classList.toggle('show');
}
```

> If you wanna add a transition for height, you should use `max-height` and `overflow` instead. It's a reference to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/how-can-i-transition-height-0-to-height-auto-using-css). I would suggest you use JS to toggle between classes instead of mixing CSS in your JS code as it makes development and debugging easier. Explanation is [here](https://www.codeconquest.com/dont-mix-html-css-javascript/).

Comment: details and summary is not a tool to show a navigation bar. It is for actual content. It is semantically wrong to use and would be confusing for assisted technologies.

Comment: Oh I didn't know it was for a navigation bar. I searched HTML semantic elements and it says that detail and summary tags are semantic?

Comment: yes, those are semantic tags to show and hide content while summary as the name is a summary of the entire content. As such it is semantically incorrect to use those semantic tags for a navigation bar. There is no summary to a navbar nor is the navbar content itself but an element to redirect to actual content. The OP used names such as **sidenav** and those elements in his code only contain anchors. carefully reading the OP question should give you enough hints about the purpose.